# Computing gradient of KL-divergence

Tags: machine-learning, approximate-inference, matrix-calculus

Consider a normal distribution $\mathcal N(\boldsymbol{\mu}(w), \boldsymbol{\Sigma}(w))$, with mean $\boldsymbol{\mu}(w)$ and covariance $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}(w)$ that are parameterized by a vector of parameters $w$. What is the gradient, with respect to $w$, of the KL divergence $\mathrm{KL}(N(\boldsymbol{\mu}(w),\boldsymbol{\Sigma}(w)) \| N(\boldsymbol{\mu}_1,\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1))$?

Comment: You'll need to edit your post to include a question.